# How to get IP address of container in docker-compse

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, docker-compose, amazon-sqs

I am trying to run the [fake_sqs gem](https://github.com/iain/fake_sqs) in a docker container in development to test my SQS integration, and have another app send messages to it.

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
app:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s Puma --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  ports:
     - 3000:3000
  links:
    - db:db
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: app.docker
    PGHOST: db
    PGUSER: postgres
    AWS_REGION: us-west-2
    AWS_QUEUE_NAME: my-queue
    AWS_ENDPOINT: http://aws.docker:4568/
fakesqs:
  build: .
  command: fake_sqs -p 4568
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  ports:
     - 4568:4568
  links:
    - db:db
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: aws.docker
    PGHOST: db
    PGUSER: postgres
    AWS_REGION: us-west-2
db:
  image: postgres
```

This works to some degree. I can send messages to the `fakesqs` using the `http://aws.docker:4568` url. The problem I am trying to solve centers around the command for the `fakesqs` container. If you run `fake_sqs` as it is written in my file, by default it sets the hostname to `0.0.0.0`. This means that when I use the [aws-sdk gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) to request queue urls, `fake_sqs` replies with the wrong host.

```
client = Aws::SQS::Client.new
client.get_queue_url(queue_name: 'my-queue').queue_url
# => http://0.0.0.0:4568/my-queue
```

I obviously can't use this url to send messages.  Instead, the url needs to be the IP of the `fakesqs` container. You can set the host url with the `-o` option (i.e. `fake_sqs -o <IP_ADDRESS> -p 4568`).

How can I access the `fakesqs` container IP address to put into the command? Do I have to set a static IP address for that container? Or is there another way I'm meant to be doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use hostname instead of IP address.

add link to fake_sqs from you app container

```
app:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s Puma --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  ports:
     - 3000:3000
  links:
    - db:db
    - fake_sqs #add this line!
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: app.docker
    PGHOST: db
    PGUSER: postgres
    AWS_REGION: us-west-2
    AWS_QUEUE_NAME: my-queue
```

and try to execute `fake_sqs -o fake_sqs -p 4568` inside your app container

Comment: This was part of the answer. The other part was I had to fork the fake_sqs gem so that I could provide a host name without changing the binding IP (https://github.com/CloverAU/fake_sqs).